# Duplicated inherited attribute

Tags: inheritance, interface, attributes, mef

```
[InheritedExport]
[LoginMetadata]
public interface ILogon
{
    bool Authenticate ( string UserName, string Password );
}

public interface ILoginMetadata
{
    string Name
    {
        get;
    }

    string Description
    {
        get;
    }
}

[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Interface, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true )]
public class LoginMetadataAttribute : ExportAttribute, ILoginMetadata
{
    public LoginMetadataAttribute ( )
        : base( typeof( ILogon ) )
    {
    }

    #region ILoginMetadata Members

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion
}

public class LogonPlugins
{
    [ImportMany( typeof( ILogon ) )]
    public List<Lazy<ILogon, ILoginMetadata>> Plugins
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public static class Logon
{
    private static LogonPlugins _Plugins = null;
    private static AggregateCatalog _Catalog = null;
    private static CompositionContainer _Container = null;

    public static LogonPlugins Plugins
    {
        get
        {
            if ( _Plugins == null )
            {
                _Plugins = new LogonPlugins( );

                _Catalog = new AggregateCatalog( );
                _Catalog.Catalogs.Add( new AssemblyCatalog( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly( ) ) );

                _Container = new CompositionContainer( _Catalog );
                _Container.ComposeParts( _Plugins );
            }

            return ( _Plugins );
        }
    }
}
```

This code meant to load extension objects - of type ILogon - using the Lazy model.
Because the ways of Lazy the objects must inherit ILogon and **MUST** have also LoginMetadata attribute declared on.
I not realy want to force the LoginMetadata so I declared it inheritable and added it to the interface with no params.
My problem is that when I **do** declare the attribute on the plugin class, the final list will contain two entries of the same plugin type. One for the empty attribute declared on the interface - and inherited; and one for the attribute declared on the plugin class.

There is a way to overcome?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 0):

One of the exports is coming from the InheritedExport applied to the ILogin interface and the second is from the LoginMetadataAttribute attribute which is also an ExportAttribute. You need to either remove the InheritedExport or remove the ExportAttribute base type from LoginMetadataAttribute.

In general if you are using metadata it should be specific for a given export so I would expect you should remove InheritedExport from the interface and expect people exporting ILogin to apply the LoginMetadataAttribute and also provide the necessary metadata. If this is the route you go I would suggest renaming it to LoginExportAttribute.